How long will a solana wallet being deactivated?
I have 2 related questions:
When I created a new wallet on Solana network and did not make any activity, how long will the wallet being deactivated?
And how long will the wallet being deactivated after the last transaction?
Many thanks!

Solana wallets do not get deactivated due to inactivity. They remain active indefinitely as long as they maintain the minimum balance required for rent-exemption. This applies both after wallet creation and after the last transaction.
